# F5 какое событие нужно оформить, при обновлении страницы

Tags: c#, blazor-client-side

веб приложение блазор использует определенные настройки пользователя.

1. **При навигации** между страницами, **вся информация сохраняется корректно** и пользователь всегда видит инофрмацию, которую он запросил при идентификации (пример: свое имя вверху страницы/данные на самой странице).

> 2. Когда же **страница обновляется, то все обнуляется** и пользователь теряет всю информацию. ПОЧЕМУ? Где искать ответы, как решить вопрос? (главное, что я дебаглю и все вроде на месте)

[Прочитала про цикл компонента](https://blazor-university.com/components/component-lifecycles/) при обновлении страницы страница входит в некоторые методы. Я на каждой странице в `OnInitializedAsync` вызываю куки, и даю значения. Прошлась по `шагам (F10/F11)`, переменные глобальные и присваивают необходимое значение, только вот на результат это не влияет, все равно страница пустая.

так же я повторила тоже самое в методах `OnAfterRender` / `OnParametersSetAsync`.

Подскажите, кто писал веб приложение сталкивались ли с похожей ситуацией, как решали, возможные примеры ?

***** Есть ли еще какое событие, которое нужно переопределить, если пользователь нажал `F5`
или просто обновил страницу нажав [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так я присваиваю данные на каждой странице:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    StaticVariable.UserConnected = await cookie.GetValueAsync<UserConnected>(StaticVariable.NessyWebCookiesLastUser);
    if (StaticVariable.UserConnected != null)
    {
        SessionSettings.name = StaticVariable.UserConnected.UserLast;
        SessionSettings.token = StaticVariable.UserConnected.UserToken;
    }

    if (SessionSettings.token != null)
    {
        StaticVariable.IfUserConnected = true;
    }

    try
    {
        if (StaticVariable.IfUserCheckedMemberMe)
        {
            StaticVariable.GetToken();
            StaticVariable.GetUserName();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var msg = e.Message;
        logger.LogWarning("some logs warning");
    }
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

***говорят ты не так делаешь, а как делать молчат, ну не так все...на маленьких тестовых проектах все просто, но вот когда разростается, тут есть случаи, которые не покажешь на примере

Comment: могу предположить что дело в куках

Comment: @AndrewStop_RU_war_in_UA если бы еще решение бы, или хотя бы путь к решению. Сколько раз уже вопрос задаю, по кусочкам решаю, а в итоге ощущение, что как будто дом из коробок. Мне бы деревья, камни....пАмАгите

Comment: @Andrew Stop_RU_war_in_UA вот при навигации, при закрытии/открытии я все данные из кук, то есть они set-ированны, НО когда я нажимаю F5, что происходит? какое событие искать. чтоб туда мои куки/методы(ну как снова открыл страницу) заполнить/вызвать

Answer (score 0):

[Порядок запуска блазор.](https://metanit.com/sharp/blazor/1.3.php)

[image: Введите сюда описание изображения]

[Этапы компонента Blazor
Компонент Blazor может пройти пять этапов:](https://blazorschool.com/tutorial/blazor-wasm/dotnet7/component-lifecycle-923500)

SetParameters: этот этап запускается при первоначальном создании компонента (параметры еще не установлены) или всякий раз, когда параметры компонента обновляются из URL-адреса или из родительского компонента. Если SetParametersAsyncметод переопределен, методы OnParametersSetи OnParametersSetAsyncне должны использоваться.
Инициализация: это этап, на котором компонент полностью построен и установлены параметры.
ParametersSet: как следует из названия, этот этап запускается всякий раз, когда параметры компонента обновляются из URL-адреса или из родительского компонента.
AfterRender: срабатывает, когда компонент проходит стадию инициализации или StateHasChangedвызывается.
Dispose: это последний шаг, когда компонент удаляется из пользовательского интерфейса. Разработчики должны очистить ресурсы, чтобы предотвратить утечку памяти или неожиданное поведение.

Вот минимальный пример на [гитхаб](https://github.com/Dev18000/TestComponentLifeCycle/blob/master/TestComponentLifeCycle/Pages/Index.razor).

На простом примере мы видим, что куки передаются, и, если обновить страницу, при дебаге мы попадаем в ОнИнитиалайз, то есть куки хранятся в навигаторе и при f5 мы их присваиваем желаемым переменным. Отвечаю на свой вопрос, и поэтому осмелюсь предположить, что так как я использую компоненты, то существует определенный цикл присваивания.

Вот Метанит говорит как раз https://metanit.com/sharp/blazor/2.10.php о иных событиях, которые можно вызвать при использовании [компонентов](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/components).

Попробуйте пересмотреть дерево перехода страниц, чтоб понять в какой момент вы теряете "данные пользователя(имя, токен...)".